# Different objects calling same method, how can I set the "caller's" property?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 15 images on my WPF application.  I want it so that whenever MouseUp on any of the images is called.. it'll call the same method.

I would like to do something similar to the psuedo code written here.. This would save so much time instead of writing 15 individual methods for each button.  How can I do something like this?

```
private void BluePick1_Image_MouseUp_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
            sender.ImageSource = something;
}
```

thank you for any help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if your event is always on a button :

```
private void ButtonMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
  ((Button)sender).ImageSource = something;
}
```

and

```
button1.MouseUp += ButtonMouseUp;
button2.MouseUp += ButtonMouseUp;
```

Comment: whoops accidentally tried to edit. but that's it? didn't think it was as simple as casting the sender... will try and come back to this, thank you!!!

Comment: chill, something came up.  i always come back to give people their credit